# Is recombination rate proportional to injection current?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Seems to say so [here](https://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~schubert/Reprints/2010-Dai-Qi-et-al-(APL)-Carrier-recombination-mechanisms-and-efficiency-droop-in-GaInN-GaN-LEDs.pdf), looking at equations 1 and 2, but why is that the case? Why is the rate of recombination affected by input current into an LED?

Reading the paper is not strictly necessary, it's just the place I got the idea that recombination rate is proportional to injection current. And I can't see any physical connection between those two quantities really.

Comment: You should formulate specifically what your question is here. You should not require from the community to work through a lengthy research paper to understand what you mean by your question.

Comment: My question doesn't necessarily require reading the paper, I thought I'd say where I got the idea that recombination rate is proportional to injection current from though. I've edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: I looked at equations (1) and (2) of the paper and gave you a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recombination rate $R$ (number of recombining electrons per unit time and unit volume) is proportional to the diode current $I$ according to equation (2) of the cited paper. This proportionality is typical for all np-diodes because the diode current $I$ is caused by the recombination of electrons and holes at the junction.

Comment: Indeed - you need to think of current 'through' a diode to be electrons and holes entering the junction region and recombining there (all of them). Electrons don't flow 'through' a diode.

Comment: @Jon Custer - You are completely right!